# How to stop PS+ Sharing with someone

Tags: ps4, psn

Hi I'm sharing my PS+ with someone who used to be my friend and I deleted his account off my ps4 but he still has mine on his and its his primary account however he doesn't know my password. Is there anyway I can stop him from taking my PSN when I pay for it?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know if you could do that but you can remotely deactivate Playstation Devices that uses your account. Just head to Playstation network then login > Account section(other settings) > Devices > Deactivate all. Then make sure you set your own PS4 as your primary account.